# How to ignore some files for Vim word complete?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Say I am working on parsing very big data files (each file has approximately several megabytes). I want to write parsing code with seeing these data files, so I have several windows in Vim, some are code files and some are data files.

In this case, Vim word completion in the insert mode is extremely slow because it tries to scan the data file. To avoid this situation, I want to ignore these data files which have non-program extension (e.g. dat, txt instead of c, rb, py), but keep watching program files. So the best case is that I can register some extensions for ignoring during word completion.

How can I achieve this? I looked at [h: 'complete'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'complete') but I could not find what I want to do. For example, `set complete-=w` in .vimrc does not satisfy me because it ignores not only data files but also program files, which completely spoils word completion.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A very simple and very obvious workaround would be to open your data files in another Vim instance or, since you are not going to *edit* them, in a pager like `less` (which happens to share many commands with Vi[m]).

Comment: Yes, I am considering it. To view everything at once (this is a part of what I want to do), I can use Screen, iTerm2 or whatever to split screen and open the data. However, I really want to find a way to do it in pure vim environment because of many reasons: `less` does not have plugins which I use even during just seeing files. In addition, if I have multiple instances of Vim in one screen with use of screen splitting by Screen for instance, I am sure I will get confused how to go to another window because it mixes Vim feature and Screen feature, which is painful.

Comment: All good points. In Vim itself, the only way I know to exclude a file from scanning is to remove it from the buffer list or unload it but that also means *not displaying it* so that defeats the purpose. Alternatively, you could use `<C-x><C-o>` and `<C-x><C-n>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options: Work with / reconfigure the completion sources in the `'complete'` option, or write a custom completion yourself.

For the latter, my [CompleteHelper library](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914) provides helper functions that make that quite simple. For example, the [SameFiletypeComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4242) (which is based on that library) only considers buffers with the same filetype. Of course, any custom completion isn't as fast as the built-in one, and my library currently is limited to buffer searches (no tags, dictionaries, etc.)

I personally would make those big data files *unlisted* via `:setlocal nobuflisted`, and open them in a separate tab page; the default for `'complete'` would then ignore those (as it doesn't contain the `U` value).

Comment: Your plugin sounds very nice, but it did not work for me. I extracted both vimballs, CompleteHelper and SameFileTypeComplete and I see SameFiletypeComplete.vim is installed with `:scriptnames`. I set `let g:SameFiletypeComplete_complete = '.,w,b'` in my plain .vimrc, then typed <C-x><C-p> but it does not search for keywords written in other windows. Local completion works as usual. Any idea what's wrong? My environment: `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jul 10 2017 18:00:13)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-703
Compiled by Homebrew`

Comment: You also need to install this library: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433 Oh, and the same filetype completion is triggered via `<C-x>=` (default; can be changed).

Comment: Worked perfectly! This is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!!